# Practicing acoustic guitar silently

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I want to practice acoustic guitar without disturbing anyone else. I want to be the only person who can hear it. But how can I do that? Would it be okay if I buy an amplifier with a headset? Will this solve my problem?

Comment: Could we get you to further elaborate on your question? It is sort of sparse as it is.

Comment: Do you mean an acoustic guitar, or an electric?  If you do mean an acoustic, how do you expect an amplifier to change how loud the acoustic guitar is on its own?

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of silent guitars on the market. These are quite similar in principle to electric violins - a solid non-resonant body and fitted with piezoelectric pickups at the bridge.  In addition headphones and possibly an amplifier will be required for silent practice.

Some are available as nylon-strung versions for classical-style guitar, as well as steel strung.

([Yamaha's range is marketed as the Silent Guitar](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/guitars-basses/silentguitars/), but other manufacturers probably make something similar; I'm not making any recommendations.)

Comment: they claim 80% quieter than an ordinary acoustic or 90% quieter than a classical...do they compare to any electric guitars that are not plugged in?

Comment: Heh, I haven't tried one. I would expect that they are **not** completely silent. I guess the steel strung versions may be as loud as an unplugged electric as Mr. Boy suggests in his answer. The nylon strung versions will probably be a bit quieter.

Answer (score 4):

The point of an acoustic guitar is that it can be heard without need for any amplification. To have an instrument that cannot be heard by others, a solid guitar is a better option. That can then be connected to a small amp, etc., and headphones. What are the reasons you don't want to be heard? They may give other options.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bit of a silly answer, but you *could* get a cheap/old acoustic guitar and rip the back off. This would kill all the acoustic resonance and you'd get hardly any noise.

But as others have said, an electric guitar is a better option unless you need an acoustic for specific reasons (which you should add to your question). However, even an unplugged electric guitar makes a reasonable amount of noise... not enough to wake your neighbours but enough to be annoying to other people in the same room.

Comment: Not a silly answer at all in my opinion. Could remove the back and possibly glue extra timber inside the soundboard to reinforce the line from the neck to the bridge. This would effectively be building a low cost, DIY semi-solid guitar.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an acoustic guitar then I would suggest that you weave a shoelace or something similar around the strings near the bridge. This should reduce the sound significantly. Another idea is to use a piece of thick paper to strum and pick instead of a plastic pick.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a toothbrush ... particularly the Oral-B CrossAction All In One Toothbrush as the tip of a bristles are longer. You can use that little part or strum hard with the entire head.

(And if you want LOUD and a different tone the Oral-B Indicator is the only toothbrush I've ever found in which the back of the head has a rounded, smooth, surface which makes is pretty comfortable for strumming ... and it's far louder and brighter because it's hard plastic.)

2. Use an electric with a acoustic pedal ... through an amp with headphones.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is quite an old question, but it has activity today so I'll chime in.

Any soft object placed under the area just in front of the bridge will greatly reduce sound of an acoustic guitar. Socks, cloth, foam padding, etc. If you look up bridge mute you can find devices especially made for this.

The real answer to this question is to find a practice space where you can play acoustic guitar un-muted. Muting the strings means you cannot hear yourself as well, and you need to hear yourself when practicing.